# UIImageOrientation documentation is incorrect

Tags: uiimageorientation

Looking through Apple's documentation for `UIImageOrientation` I notice that the images that go with the descriptions are incorrect.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimageorientation

This has been painful for me, so I'm going to leave this here, with the correct images in the answer in case others find the same.

If people think this shouldn't be here, please comment / vote down and I'll remove.

Comment: Including a link to a production web site in a question isn't very helpful - it's not searchable, requires users to click through to see what you're describing, and is subject to change which will invalidate this question. Could you edit to present the problem in a way that others struggling with the issue might find it? While you're at it, the "documentation" tag is not valid, so you can remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I got the correct images:

```
extension UIImage {

    var normalised: UIImage {

        if imageOrientation == .up {
            return self
        }

        var normalisedImage: UIImage

        let format = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat.default()
        format.scale = scale
        format.opaque = true
        format.prefersExtendedRange = false
        normalisedImage = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size, format: format).image { _ in
            draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
        }

        return normalisedImage
    }

    func translated(to orientation: UIImageOrientation) -> UIImage {
        guard let cgImage = cgImage else {

            return self
        }

        return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage, scale: 1, orientation: orientation).normalised
    }
}
```

Then using this image as the "base"

[image]

[image]